# I need to use Cross Apply to get a table with a value for every date

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a query that returns these results:

```
ID     | From        | To         |  Value
------ | ---------   | ---------- | -------
8      | 1/1/2018    | 2/28/2018  |  .03
8      | 3/1/2018    | 4/30/2018  |  .04
9      | 1/1/2018    | 1/31/2018  |  .05
```

What I need is this:

```
ID     | Date        | Value        
------ | ---------   | ---------- 
8      | 1/1/2018    | .03  
8      | 2/1/2018    | .03  
8      | 3/1/2018    | .04
8      | 4/1/2018    | .04
9      | 1/1/2018    | .05
```

I have researched and it seems like Cross Apply needs to be used here along with date table, but just not sure how to use this operator.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach is using an ad-hoc tally table within the CROSS APPLY.  A numbers or calendar table would do the trick as well.

**Example**

```
Select A.ID
      ,B.Date
      ,A.Value
 From  YourTable A
 Cross Apply (
              Select Top (DateDiff(MONTH,A.[From],A.[To])+1) 
                     Date=DateAdd(MONTH,-1+Row_Number() Over (Order By (Select Null)),A.[From]) 
               From  master..spt_values n1
             ) B
```

**Returns**

[image]

> **EDIT - If Open to a UDF**

I'll often use a UDF to create dynamic date/time ranges.  It is faster than a recursive cte and it is parameter driven.  You supply the date/time range, datepart, and increment.

**Example of UDF**

```
Select A.ID
      ,Date = cast(B.RetVal as date)
      ,A.Value
 From YourTable A
 Cross Apply [dbo].[udf-Range-Date](A.[From],A.[To],'MM',1) B
```

**The UDF if Interested**

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[udf-Range-Date] (@R1 datetime,@R2 datetime,@Part varchar(10),@Incr int)
Returns Table
Return (
    with cte0(M)   As (Select 1+Case @Part When 'YY' then DateDiff(YY,@R1,@R2)/@Incr When 'QQ' then DateDiff(QQ,@R1,@R2)/@Incr When 'MM' then DateDiff(MM,@R1,@R2)/@Incr When 'WK' then DateDiff(WK,@R1,@R2)/@Incr When 'DD' then DateDiff(DD,@R1,@R2)/@Incr When 'HH' then DateDiff(HH,@R1,@R2)/@Incr When 'MI' then DateDiff(MI,@R1,@R2)/@Incr When 'SS' then DateDiff(SS,@R1,@R2)/@Incr End),
         cte1(N)   As (Select 1 From (Values(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)) N(N)),
         cte2(N)   As (Select Top (Select M from cte0) Row_Number() over (Order By (Select NULL)) From cte1 a, cte1 b, cte1 c, cte1 d, cte1 e, cte1 f, cte1 g, cte1 h ),
         cte3(N,D) As (Select 0,@R1 Union All Select N,Case @Part When 'YY' then DateAdd(YY, N*@Incr, @R1) When 'QQ' then DateAdd(QQ, N*@Incr, @R1) When 'MM' then DateAdd(MM, N*@Incr, @R1) When 'WK' then DateAdd(WK, N*@Incr, @R1) When 'DD' then DateAdd(DD, N*@Incr, @R1) When 'HH' then DateAdd(HH, N*@Incr, @R1) When 'MI' then DateAdd(MI, N*@Incr, @R1) When 'SS' then DateAdd(SS, N*@Incr, @R1) End From cte2 )

    Select RetSeq = N+1
          ,RetVal = D 
     From  cte3,cte0 
     Where D<=@R2
)
/*
Max 100 million observations -- Date Parts YY QQ MM WK DD HH MI SS
Syntax:
Select * from [dbo].[udf-Range-Date]('2016-10-01','2020-10-01','YY',1) 
Select * from [dbo].[udf-Range-Date]('2016-01-01','2017-01-01','MM',1) 
*/
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply and apologies for not clarifying - I just need the value for each month, not every single day.

Comment: @JasonC Simply change DAY to MONTH.  Updating in a moment

Comment: @JasonC Just an after thought.  What if FROM is 2018-01-17, what would the next value be?

Comment: What is this sorcery?!  Did not know about master..spt_values, and to be honest have no idea how that worked but it did.  Also to answer your other question - in this case the from will always be beginning of month to EOM.  Thanks for your help on this!

Comment: @JasonC  master..spt_values is just a known table in SQL Server with approx 2,500 rows of data.  ANY table of appropriate size will do.  We use this table to generate a sequence of Row_Numbers.  We then use these row numbers in the DateAdd function.  If not comfortable with Row_NUmber() or the other windowing functions, it is well worth your time ... they can be invaluable.

Comment: @JasonC  Just for fun try Select Top 10 Row_Number() over (Order By (Select null)) From  master..spt_values

Comment: @JasonC Then run 
 Select Top 10 DateAdd(DAY,-1+Row_Number() over (Order By (Select null)),'2017-01-01') From  master..spt_values

Comment: @JasonC See EDIT - I added a frequently used UDF

Answer (score 3):

Since [John Cappelletti](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1570000/john-cappelletti) mentioned [calendar tables](https://www.google.com/search?q=t+sql+calendar+table&oq=tsql+calendar), and since I'm always looking for an excuse to extol the virtue of using them, I'll just point out that if you have a Calendar table then the solution is simply:

```
select T.id, S.date, T.value from YourTable T
cross apply
(
    select date from Calendar where date between T.[from] and T.[to] and day_of_month = 1
) S order by T.id, S.date asc
```

Which yields:

```
id      date       value  
------ ----------  ------- 
8      2018-01-01  0.03    
8      2018-02-01  0.03    
8      2018-03-01  0.04    
8      2018-04-01  0.04    
9      2018-01-01  0.05
```

And here's  all it takes to create a Calendar table:

```
create table Calendar
(
    id int primary key identity,
    date datetime,
    day_of_week as datepart(dw, date),
    day_of_month as datepart(d, date),
    month as datepart(m, date),
    year as datepart(yy, date),
    day_name as datename(dw, date)
    --etc...
)

--and populate

declare @day datetime
set @day = '1/1/2000'

while @day <= '12/31/2100'
begin

    insert Calendar select @day
    set @day = dateadd(day, 1, @day)

end
```

Comment: Thank you both!  One final question - how do I make contact with experts directly and privately on a contract basis for small projects, is this possible?

Comment: @JasonC -- My contact info is in my profile. Kind regards.